# How can I limit draggable distance?

Tags: unity-game-engine, draggable, drag

I tried to make a draggable drawer, I used this code:

```
     void OnMouseDrag() {
         Vector3 curScreenPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);
         Vector3 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint) + offset;

         //Debug.Log(curPosition[0]);
         curPosition.y = gameObject.transform.position.y;
         curPosition.z = gameObject.transform.position.z;
         //curPosition.x = Mathf.Clamp(gameObject.transform.position.x,-3.0F,3.0F);
        transform.position = curPosition;

     }
```

How can I limit a drag range of x? Because I don't want to have something like this:

[image]

I tried to use Mathf.Clamp, but it doesn't work well.

Thank you! And sorry for my english.

Comment: You'll still probably need to tweak it, but it seems likely that `Mathf.Clamp()` doesn't work well beacuse you're clamping `curPosition.x` between `worldPosition.x - 3.f` and `worldPosition.x + 3.f`. Try `Mathf.Clamp(gameObject.transform.position.x, gameObject.transform.position.x - 3.0F, gameObject.transform.position.x + 3.0F);` :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using a [Physics Joints](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/physics-joints), more preciselly a [ConfigurableJoint](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/physics-joints). You can set a limit to the distance your joint can travel on each axis (I used it once to do some drawers).